# How to make SQL query from this structure table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
Initial:
1_ = country
2_ = gender 
3_ = purpose
```

[image]

How to make SQL query show data like this

[image]

Comment: don't post pictures. rather post them as text.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yet, please post what you have done so far at least. 

You can't just expect people to do things for you. And specify just one RDBMS...

Comment: sorry for the picture that I use to ask. I'm new in SO. next times I'll use your suggestions. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this(this is a `mysql` approach), and next time please post your table schema with text not pictures if you want to ask a question in SO.

```
select
    u.id,
    u.name,
    max(case when ud.code like '1_%' then fc.code_name else '' end) as country,
    max(case when ud.code like '2_%' then fc.code_name else '' end) as gender,
    max(case when ud.code like '3_%' then fc.code_name else '' end) as purpose,
    group_concat(distinct vt.visit_to) as visit_to
from t_users u
left join t_user_details ud
on u.id = ud.id_user
left join t_field_code fc
on ud.code = fc.code
left join t_visit_to vt
on u.id = vt.id_user
group by u.id, u.name
```

Comment: sorry for the picture that I use to ask. I'm new in SO. next times I'll use your suggestions. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job more or less:

```
SELECT user.id,
       user.name,
       country.code_name AS country,
       gender.code_name  AS gender,
       purpose.code_name AS purpose,
       visit.to_to
FROM   t_users        AS user
JOIN   t_user_details AS details
  ON   user.id = details.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_field_code AS country
             ON details.code = country.code
            AND country.code LIKE '1_%'
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_field_code AS gender
             ON details.code = gender.code
            AND gender.code LIKE '2_%'
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_field_code AS purpose
             ON details.code = purpose.code
            AND purpose.code LIKE '3_%'
LEFT OUTER JOIN t_visit_to AS visit
             ON user.id = visit.id_user
ORDER BY user.id;
```

The only problem is that it gives multiple rows in case the user has more places to visit.